# Canvas (Chart.js) resizing properly on Chrome while on Safari it not even displayed

Tags: css, google-chrome, canvas, safari, chart.js

Im using 2 javascript Libaries. The first one is gridstack.js via which I establish draggable and droppable div element, while with chart.js charts are implemented. Now problem is that resizing of gridstack div element with chart properly works on Chrome while on Safari chart is not displayed.

Chrome
[image]

Safari

[image]

home.blade.php

```
<style type="text/css">
      .povr{ margin-top:50px;}

      @media (max-width: 1060px) {
      .grid-stack-item {
        position: relative !important;
        width: auto !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        top: auto !important;
        margin-bottom: 20px;

      }
      .grid-stack-item .ui-resizable-handle {
        display: none;
      }

      .grid-stack {
        height: auto !important;
      }
    }

    .container-fluid{
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .grid-stack-item-content{
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;

    }
    .grid-stack-item-content:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }

    #chart {
    position: relative;
    width:99.9% 
    }

#chart > .monitoring-chart {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

}

</style>


        <div class="grid-stack" data-gs-width="12" data-gs-animate="yes"> 
              <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="{{$loginElement->data_gs_x}}" data-gs-y="{{$loginElement->data_gs_y}}" data-gs-width="{{$loginElement->data_gs_width}}" data-gs-height="{{$loginElement->data_gs_height}}" id="{{$loginElement->id}}" data-element-id="{{$loginElement->element_id}}"> 
                                      @include('dashboard.login_tile') 
                             </div>   

                              <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="{{$uploadElement->data_gs_x}}" data-gs-y="{{$uploadElement->data_gs_y}}" data-gs-width="{{$uploadElement->data_gs_width}}" data-gs-height="{{$uploadElement->data_gs_height}}" id="{{$uploadElement->id}}" data-element-id="{{$uploadElement->element_id}}"> 
                                     @include('dashboard.upload_tile')
                              </div>
       </div>
```

login.blade.php

```
<div class="card grid-stack-item-content">
      <div class="card-header container-fluid" id="dashboard-header">
                <div class="row dashboard-row">
                    <div class="col-3 dashboard-icon-div text-center">
                        <h1 class="dashboard-h1"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <h4 class="card-title dashboard-card-title"> {{ trans('app.logins_upper_firsts') }}</h4>
                    </div>    
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-card-tool ml-auto" id="authDaterange">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <span>{{ trans('app.last_7_days_upper_first') }}</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                         </button>

                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="chart" id="chart">

        <canvas class="monitoring-chart" id="authChart" style="height: 150px"></canvas>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```